# Socket in background state iOS

Tags: ios, sockets, voip, background-mode

Maybe someone ever solve the problem with stable connection to server when application is in background? I need to transfer audio data from server to client app. 
I know about all hacks for iOS how to keep alive application, but I need legal methods to solve this problem. Maybe you have any idea?
I found that I can send VoIP push to device that will wakeup my app and then establish tcp connect to my server but this socket will be keep alive about 30 seconds (as I see in log, every 3 seconds fires timer in iOS app that send data to server) this is not enough for me.

Comment: Did you check the UIBackgroundModes?

Comment: You can't keep a raw socket alive when your app is in the background. You use PushKit pushes to wake your app when there is a specific event. You can use background URL sessions to upload/download files in the background https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system/downloading_files_in_the_background

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this project https://github.com/SmallSharpToolsOpenSource/Speakerbox will be helpful for someone.
And this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lXJ1LDjL4Os

And official answer from Apple tech support:

> PushKit is how voip apps can
>   reliable receive silent notifications, while CallKit is basically a UI
>   framework voip apps can use to notify the user about calls.  Note that there
>   is NOT any direct connection within the APIs- for example, a voip app can
>   generate a local notification (instead of using CallKit) or simply do nothing
>   and “ignore” the notification entirely.  Similarly, a voip app could “fake” a
>   call at anytime by simply telling CallKit that there was an incoming call (our
>   sample code for CallKit did exactly this).
>
> Anything your app could previously have done when
>   it received voip socket traffic, it could also do when it received a PushKit
>   notification.
>
> Standard voip apps
>   actually operate in two COMPETELY unrelated “modes”:
>
> 1) While waiting for an incoming call, the app is suspended until “something”
>   (PushKit OR a voip socket) wakes the app to tell it about the call.
>
> 2) Once a call has started, the app has an active audio session and is relying
>   an the standard “background audio” behavior of iOS, just like a wide variety
>   of other audio apps (for example, any streaming music app).